# In TypeScipt with strictNullChecks flag set to false, is there any benefit to declaring variable as nullable?

Tags: typescript

I'm working in a complex TypeScript project with many people working on it at the same time. The `strictNullChecks` flag in `tsconfig.json` is set to `false`. I don't like it, but it's not my decision. In the project I have a class that declares a variable, say `lorem`, of type `Ipsum`, which is another class (so not a simple value type like `number` or `boolean`). Is there any benefit to declaring my variable like this:

```
public lorem: Ipsum | null;
```

I could instead write this:

```
public lorem: Ipsum;
```

As I understand, because the `strictNullChecks` flag is set to `false`, both of those declaration are equivalent. However I want to convey that `lorem` can sometimes be `null` and that this behaviour is expected. But if `strictNullChecks` flag is set to `false` it means that all variables can be `null`. So is there any benefit to explicitly allowing `null` or should I keep it simple by declaring my variable as just of type `Ipsum`?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `lorem` as `Ipsum | null` will not make typescript throw an error if you're trying to access properties from `Ipsum` without checking whether its `null` first, so you gain little to no value from it (except it is a little clearer for the developer that it can indeed be `null`).

The following code with `public lorem: Ipsum | null;` will throw the same runtime error as it would without the `| null`:

```
type Ipsum = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  city: string;
};

class Foo {
  public lorem: Ipsum | null;

  public doSomething(): void {
    // will fail because lorem is not initialized.
    this.lorem.id.toString();
  }
}

// Cannot read properties of undefined
new Foo().doSomething();
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8zxelw?file=index.ts)

Comment: I still don't understand. I'm asking in the context where `strictNullChecks` flag is explicitly `false`. In that case I don't see a difference you said I'd see. 
[Here's an example of what I mean](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECSAOECuBbaBvAUNH0CWAJgFzQB2qARgKYBOA3JgL6aYhUAu0IA9jVSgEYSCZGgC8ZJCBAM2nHnxQAmYYlTQAPpOnQJ5aQ1a9+AgHSFT7bgGV2NPKQDmACgCUs48vMFLNuw5d3IA). Comment `lorem1` or `lorem2` lines and see. The result is the same - error at runtime. But at compile they are the same. So is just a preference thing?

Comment: @Razwill Sorry for the misunderstanding, all I wanted to show is that there is indeed no difference between the two, it's just a visual for the developer to see that it can indeed be `null` and that he may need to check for null if he intends to access that property. There's no difference, it's just preference whether to include ` | null` or not.